# Write into file in python

Tags: python, debian

I am trying to make a command in python that will create new aliases by writing into ~/.bashrc, my code goes as followed:

```
new_alias = raw_input("Choose alias name > ")
alias_command = raw_input("Write alias command > ")

with open("/test/text","r") as f2:
    with open("text","w+") as f1:
            f1.write(new_alias + alias_command)
            f1.seek(0,0)
            command = f1.read()
```

However when I open the text file nothing is written inside of it, so my question is what did I do wrong in this one?

Comment: What is the point of the `f2` file?

Comment: Are you sure you're writing to the correct file?  When you open a file using a relative path (ie. `passwd`), it uses the current working directory (`os.getcwd()`).  It's possible it's writing out to a different location and you're looking at a file that's not getting modified.

Comment: Yea you were right, I specified the location of the text file and now it wrote inside of it. Thank you :)

Comment: However now it overwrites what was previously there, any idea why?

Comment: `w+` will overwrite.  If you want to append, use `a`

Comment: Ok I didn't know that, last question, any idea how i can make it write in a new line every time I run the script instead of him writing in the same line?